# File Format - How to open this extension

Tags: file-format

I received several images with the .irt file extension that I am unable to open. I am not familiar with this file format.
How can I open them?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Have you tried searching for information about that file extension? If not, why not?

Comment: "I received  ... " then why are you not asking the person who sent them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean Infrared Termography files.

You may open them in [SATIR Report](http://www.sat.com.cn/en/products.aspx?n_id=203&dn_id=172) (Windows).